# How can I find the links of videos on youtube by searching a topic using youtube API for android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I know how to use Android youtube API to get thumbnails of images using video id, but how can I find thumbnails of videos by using the video title?

Comment: Just read the [Youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)  well and you will realize you can using `media thumbnail`

Comment: Actually i am beginner and I have read it but couldn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**To parse YouTube Searched Video Json Feed use this link:**
[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=my+love+by+shovon](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=my%20love%20by%20shovon)

`Here "my love by shovon" is searched item.`

Parse it using any json parser and get the YouTube video of searched item.**Use this Json parser.**

```
public JSONObject getJson()
{
    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=my%20love%20by%20shovon");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    try {
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // json is UTF-8 by default i beleive
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    JSONObject job = null;
    try {
        job = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return job;
}
```

Comment: can you explain how to do with this please?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check and use this json object for your apps. Happy coding.

Comment: If this answer solve your problem please make this right answer :) 
Happy coding.

Comment: Dear Mahmudul your code help me a lot and i was able to pick thumbnail of video from youtube..Thank you again.